# How to search for multiple vectors in vectordb

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

am looking a way how i can look for multiple vectors with vectordb since it always look for scores.
for example this is my query

```
query-"can i get hydogen peroxide, hedex tabs and paracetamol?"
```

now when i search with pinecone or any db it gives me these

```
0.66: Paracetamol Susp 120mg - Sheladol
0.65: Paracetamol 500mg Tablets 10s - SHELADOL
0.62: Paracetamol TIN 500mg - SHELADOL
0.61: Zenadol-Paracetamol Tabs 500mg 100s
0.61: Elymol-Paracetamol 500mg Tabs.
0.6: Paracetamol 500mg Tab - Pan Advance
0.6: Paracetamol Infusion 1%w/v 100ml
0.58: Paracetamol susp 100ml-ZENADOL
0.57: Paracetamol Susp 100ml - COSMOL
0.56: Paracetamol Blister 500mg Tabs
0.56: Paracetamol Susp.- DOLOMOL
0.56: Paracetamol Susp 100ml - Elymol
0.53: CALPOL Paracetamol 60ml
0.49: Antihistamine Cream
0.49: Antihistamine Cream
0.49: Antihistamine Cream
```

to which there is no almost two product in the list top k= 20. but they are there in vector db untill you search one item separately. how can i achieve so i can get all mentioned products?

cany somebody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After a time i found an answer. I was using pinecone and later changed to faiss. These vectordb doesn't support multiple vectors in one query. Instead they search that multiple vector query and compare to what resemble the most with that query.instead i had to look for other multiple query vectordb. I tried elasticsearch and it works fine. So for anyone who will counter same problem, for now use that or any db with multiple search. Untill later other updates and improvements.